# How can we pick html elements value using web driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Hi i want to get value of html element using web driver how can i get it?I am explaining the scenario as below. I have a span element as below with value between the starting and closing tag .How can i get it?

```
<span id="foo">
    some value
</span>
```

Comment: @ down voters I have asked this question before 1 year and you are downvoting it now

Comment: @ deepak. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209305/user-making-inappropriate-edits-with-backticks) is probably the reason for the downvote. The "meta" effect.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `webElement.getText()` for that.

I worte a small unit test for you:

```
public class TestGetText
{
    @Test
    public void shouldReadSomevalue()
    {
        final WebDriver webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        webDriver.get("http://s2server.de/stackoverflow/11719445.html");

        final WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
        final String text = webElement.getText();

        assertEquals("some value", text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually getText() giving blank string and getAttribute("value") giving null value

Comment: Can you past the html snippet also?

Comment: Ya sure Christian below is my html <span id="lbHome">5712913742</span>

Comment: Hm, i guess there is some other problem. Because .getText() should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution -

```
String test = driver.findElement(By.id("lbHome")).getText();
System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: I am getting blank string by this method

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the element using XPath instead of ID, then using either

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(“xpath for your lbl“)).getText()`

or

`String st = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“xpath to your lbl“)).getAttribute(“value”);`

Source : [SeleniumWiki](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/webdriver/using-gettext-in-selenium-2-webdriver/)